# select distinct name and username on each window partition on presto

Tags: sql, distinct, window-functions, presto, amazon-athena

I am using window function on presto to get the distinct name and username row of each group. I did apply the `ROW_NUMBER()` on my **name** column for Partition with **datetime** column as order by and I get below result

**Current Output:**

```
name    top_user     Count           Date         Price  Percent  Volume      username   
ENZC    1            5   2021-03-07 08:11:14.000 0.1189  45.05   86131409    DeviantImmortal
ENZC    5            5   2021-03-07 08:11:14.000 0.1189  45.05   86131409    OtcRock
ENZC    2            5   2021-03-07 08:11:14.000 0.1189  45.05   86131409    OtcRock
ENZC    3            5   2021-03-07 08:11:14.000 0.1189  45.05   86131409    STOCKAHOLIC55
ENZC    4            5   2021-03-07 08:11:14.000 0.1189  45.05   86131409    stockpro20
HCMC    3            5   2021-03-07 08:34:33.000 0.0002  15.2    1376689232  Barta57
HCMC    5            5   2021-03-07 08:34:33.000 0.0002  15.2    1376689232  PennyProfitPro
HCMC    2            5   2021-03-07 08:34:33.000 0.0002  15.2    1376689232  Stocktipstoday1
HCMC    1            5   2021-03-07 08:34:33.000 0.0002  15.2    1376689232  TTrader1976
HCMC    4            5   2021-03-07 08:34:33.000 0.0002  15.2    1376689232  stockpro20
HQGE    5            6   2021-03-07 07:40:38.000 -0.0017 -16.04  63596752    BerkshireCapGrp
HQGE    1            6   2021-03-07 07:40:38.000 -0.0017 -16.04  63596752    OwnThePlayOTC
HQGE    2            6   2021-03-07 07:40:38.000 -0.0017 -16.04  63596752    PennyStockGeeks
HQGE    3            6   2021-03-07 07:40:38.000 -0.0017 -16.04  63596752    TaylorB16445829
HQGE    4            6   2021-03-07 07:40:38.000 -0.0017 -16.04  63596752    iammpremm
LTNC    2            8   2021-03-07 08:33:19.000 0.0028  10.73   293126083   BigTawno
LTNC    5            8   2021-03-07 08:33:19.000 0.0028  10.73   293126083   Faith03777244
LTNC    3            8   2021-03-07 08:33:19.000 0.0028  10.73   293126083   OneTickMoline
LTNC    1            8   2021-03-07 08:33:19.000 0.0028  10.73   293126083   OneTickMoline
LTNC    4            8   2021-03-07 08:33:19.000 0.0028  10.73   293126083   Stock_Pop
OZSC    2           10  2021-03-07 08:34:38.000 0.0685  72.87   330616866   JZavitka
OZSC    3           10  2021-03-07 08:34:38.000 0.0685  72.87   330616866   JZavitka
OZSC    1           10  2021-03-07 08:34:38.000 0.0685  72.87   330616866   S_AnglinIV
OZSC    4           10  2021-03-07 08:34:38.000 0.0685  72.87   330616866   S_AnglinIV
OZSC    5           10  2021-03-07 08:34:38.000 0.0685  72.87   330616866   claydeath1
SANP    2           5   2021-03-07 08:11:38.000 0.0049  101.04  907907634   1deadmanx
SANP    3           5   2021-03-07 08:11:38.000 0.0049  101.04  907907634   BillTsamis
SANP    5           5   2021-03-07 08:11:38.000 0.0049  101.04  907907634   Fluffypillows9
SANP    1           5   2021-03-07 08:11:38.000 0.0049  101.04  907907634   Fluffypillows9
```

**Current Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT  name, username , datetime, message, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY datetime ASC) AS top_user FROM table_name 
)
WHERE top_user < 6 ORDER BY name
```

**Expected Output:** get **distinct name and username for each window partition** i.e no two row of any window has same name and username

```
name    top_user     Count           Date         Price  Percent  Volume      username   
ENZC    1            5   2021-03-07 08:11:14.000 0.1189  45.05   86131409    DeviantImmortal
ENZC    2            5   2021-03-07 08:11:14.000 0.1189  45.05   86131409    OtcRock
ENZC    3            5   2021-03-07 08:11:14.000 0.1189  45.05   86131409    STOCKAHOLIC55
ENZC    4            5   2021-03-07 08:11:14.000 0.1189  45.05   86131409    stockpro20
HCMC    3            5   2021-03-07 08:34:33.000 0.0002  15.2    1376689232  Barta57
HCMC    5            5   2021-03-07 08:34:33.000 0.0002  15.2    1376689232  PennyProfitPro
HCMC    2            5   2021-03-07 08:34:33.000 0.0002  15.2    1376689232  Stocktipstoday1
HCMC    1            5   2021-03-07 08:34:33.000 0.0002  15.2    1376689232  TTrader1976
HCMC    4            5   2021-03-07 08:34:33.000 0.0002  15.2    1376689232  stockpro20
HQGE    5            6   2021-03-07 07:40:38.000 -0.0017 -16.04  63596752    BerkshireCapGrp
HQGE    1            6   2021-03-07 07:40:38.000 -0.0017 -16.04  63596752    OwnThePlayOTC
HQGE    2            6   2021-03-07 07:40:38.000 -0.0017 -16.04  63596752    PennyStockGeeks
HQGE    3            6   2021-03-07 07:40:38.000 -0.0017 -16.04  63596752    TaylorB16445829
HQGE    4            6   2021-03-07 07:40:38.000 -0.0017 -16.04  63596752    iammpremm
LTNC    2            8   2021-03-07 08:33:19.000 0.0028  10.73   293126083   BigTawno
LTNC    5            8   2021-03-07 08:33:19.000 0.0028  10.73   293126083   Faith03777244
LTNC    3            8   2021-03-07 08:33:19.000 0.0028  10.73   293126083   OneTickMoline
LTNC    4            8   2021-03-07 08:33:19.000 0.0028  10.73   293126083   Stock_Pop
OZSC    2           10  2021-03-07 08:34:38.000 0.0685  72.87   330616866   JZavitka
OZSC    1           10  2021-03-07 08:34:38.000 0.0685  72.87   330616866   S_AnglinIV
OZSC    5           10  2021-03-07 08:34:38.000 0.0685  72.87   330616866   claydeath1
SANP    2           5   2021-03-07 08:11:38.000 0.0049  101.04  907907634   1deadmanx
SANP    3           5   2021-03-07 08:11:38.000 0.0049  101.04  907907634   BillTsamis
SANP    1           5   2021-03-07 08:11:38.000 0.0049  101.04  907907634   Fluffypillows9
```

Comment: Your question is totally unclear.  There is no column called "stock".  It is not clear what a "group" is, nor how you are choosing which rows to show.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sir. by each group by I meant same `name` should not have same username on multiple rows as I have available username for that user already exists so it should be different otherwise same is OK

Comment: @GordonLinoff please have a look, I've edited and posted the full query now

Comment: Do you have duplicate rows in the table?

Comment: @forpas sir, actually multiple `username` for each `name` column that's why I want **distinct** `name and username` combination while using partition

Comment: I see that there are multiple usernames for each name, but I also see that there are duplicate usernames for each name, like OtcRock twice for EZNC. But also the full rows are the same. Is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to filter out the duplicate usernames by partitioning first by name and username and once again by name only:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY datetime) rn2
  FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, username ORDER BY datetime) rn1
    FROM tablename
  ) t1
  WHERE t1.rn1 = 1 
) t2
WHERE t2.rn2 < 6
```

Comment: You  are a supper star sir :)